What should the type be on a variable or function parameter that can accept any Regex pattern made with RegexBuilder?
Suppose I created a pattern using RegexBuilder like this:
let emailPattern = Regex {
    Capture {
        ZeroOrMore {
            OneOrMore(.word)
            "."
        }
        OneOrMore(.word)
    }
    "@"
    Capture {
        OneOrMore(.word)
        OneOrMore {
            "."
            OneOrMore(.word)
        }
    }
}

And I wanted a function that could take this or any other pattern like this...
func doSomethingWithPattern(pattern: ???) {
    // Implementation...
}

What would the type be?

Does some RegexComponent works?

It does! Thank you. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

This is what ended up working for a function:
func doSomethingWithPattern(pattern: some RegexComponent) {
    // ...
}

If you wanted to store your Regex in a variable in a struct you would need to do this:
struct Foo<Regex: RegexComponent> {
    let pattern: Regex

     func matches(string: String) -> Bool {
         return string.firstMatch(of: pattern) != nil
     }
}

